# Problems integrating MongoDB and Django 1.5

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to use MongoDB as database backend for my Django project. Although there are many discussions on the net, I'm having troubles to integrate them well.

My goals:

- use default Django (so no django-nonrel, which is still to 1.3)
- integrate them so that authentication is backed by MongoDB (i.e. the
  default `User` model) as well as the sessions thing.
- if possible, still have a ORM-like query system

As I understand that, [`mongoengine`](http://mongoengine.org/) could meet all my requirements, but I'm having troubles making it work correclty.
Docs say to ignore DATABASES setting. If I don't specify it, Django raises an error, while if I fill it, Django creates that database and does not use my MongoDB instance, even though I call connect() later in the file. When I run `syncdb` Django uses the other database (the one I specified in the DATABASES setting) and not MongoDB. So when I fire up MongoDB shell I can see the database is created, but the only collection is startup_log, which I never created and I suspect it's created automatically.

Comment: I found an issue on Github, still unsolved: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/172

Comment: Please provide your settings.py, and what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a change in the default requirements does adding a dummy backend to your settings help?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. An alternative way I found is to keep an sqlite db so that syncdb certainly works.